# ASP.Net UpdatePanel error when trying to find TargetControlID

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a web app, with MasterPages. On one of the content pages I am trying to use an UpdatePanel, to disable and enable certain fields.

The UpdatePanel trigger is set to a dropdownlist, however when the page loads I receive an error saying that the control ID of the dropdownlist cannot be found. I tried the simple ID (cboEventType) and the full registered ID within the HTML Markup during runtime (ctl00_maincontentholder_wpControls_cboEventType), but after trying both of the these I am still receiving the error that the TargetControlID cannot be found.

The dropdownlist control is set to visible during design time so it is not hidden on page load. What can be the issue?

Comment: Is the drop down list located outside of the content page?

Comment: No it is located within the content page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're receiving this error because the control does not exist in the master page; it exists on the page.

I think you'll have to do something like this to get it working:

```
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(cboEventType);
```

Comment: the master page is not being updated, the content page is. so shouldn't it be able to find it if I state "ctl00_maincontentholder_wpControls_cboEventType"?

Comment: I don't think that will work, and using the ClientID probably isn't a good idea anyway. The solution above is much cleaner and has fewer potential ramifications.

Comment: This did not work still receiving "A control with ID 'cboEventType' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'pnlControl'."

Comment: You need to take cboEventType out of the triggers section. The solution above will achieve the same thing as the PostBackTrigger.

Comment: With an AJAX UpdatePanel, you need to tell it which control triggers it to update

Comment: Ok well I am not getting the error anymore, yet the entire page is updating not just the update panel.

Comment: The same thing would happen with the PostBackTrigger, wouldn't it?

Comment: Ok forgive me if logic is beyond my level of intelligence, but UpdatePanels only update just what is inside the panel not the entire page at least that is what I have witnessed int he past

Comment: Yes, but that's only when the actions performed are all AJAX driven - anything that's not AJAX driven won't be updated, because the page technically hasn't posted back. If you have a control that needs to perform a full postback though, the entire page will be updated, including the contents of the update panel.

Comment: Not true, because in the past I have used update panels with grid views (loading) and buttons adding things to databases, and just that updatepanel gets updated. This dropdownlist does not need to perform a full postback, All I want to do is disable controls within the UpdatePanel

Comment: If that's what you're looking to do, then why do you need to define a trigger for it? If you don't define any triggers, everything in the UpdatePanel will be asynchronous. Were you looking to add it as an AsynchPostBackTrigger?

Comment: Ok got it working, instead of RegisterPostBackControl, I needed to user RegisterAsyncPostBackControl. Thank you for helping

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry, I thought you wanted that dropdown to do a postback.

Comment: That is ok, no apologies needed. At least you had me thinking and got me looking in the correct spot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ClientID? or the ID? My guess is that your not using the ClientID.

Comment: within ASP.Net you specificy which control is the target by either selecting it on the properties  or manually entering it in the HTML markup "TargetControlID='cboEventType'" or "TargetControlID='ctl00_maincontentholder_wpControls_cboEventType'"